# What are the integers that belong to $\overline{\rm A \cup B}$?

Tags: logic

Consider the following predicates with the set of positive integers as the domain:

$P (x): x <10 → x$ is prime

$Q (x): x <5 → x$ is odd

Let $A$ and $B$ be the sets defined as

$A = {x ∈ \mathbb {Z^+}  | P (x)}$

$B = {x ∈ \mathbb {Z^+} | ¬Q (x)}$

What are the integers that belong to $\overline{\rm A \cup  B}$? Justify the answer.

I don't know how to do this exercise, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $R(x) = C \to D$ is true if $C$ and $D$ are both true, or if $C$ is false.

And $R(X) = C\to D$ is false if $C$ is true and $D$ is false.

So $A$ is the set of positive integers where $x< 10 \to x$ is prime is true.  That is the of integers were $x< 10$ and $x$ is prime ($2,3,5,7$) and the integers where $x \ge 10$ ($10,11,12,13,.....$)$.

So $A = \{2,3,5,7,10,11,12,13,.....\}$.

And $B$ is the set of positive integers where $x < 5\to x$ is odd is false.  That is the set of integers were $x < 5$ and $x$ is even $(2,4)$.

So $B = \{2,4\}$.

So $A \cup B = \{2,3,4,5,7,10,11,12,13,14,....\}$ and $\overline {A\cup B}$ is everthing that *isn't* $\{2,3,4,5,7,10,11,12,13,14,....\}$.

So $\overline {A\cup B}=\{1,6,8,9\}$.